# How could I us ULFM in MPI. What needs to be done to enable these function and capabilities

Tags: compiler-errors, mpi

Hi I am new to MPI and not able to run ULFM mitigation capabilities in a MPI program. for instance.
error: ‘MPI_ERR_PROC_FAILED’ undeclared (first use in this function)

What should I do to enable ULFT capaibilities in a program.

Do I need to configure something?
If Yes can someone provide me with steps?

Answer (score 0):

ULFM is not yet part of the MPI Standard and is a research effort being implemented in a few places. You need to make sure you have an implementation that supports it and follow any implementation-specific instructions to enable it.

For instance, if you are using the Open MPI fork available at fault-tolerance.org, you should use the instructions available on their website: http://fault-tolerance.org/ulfm/ulfm-setup/.

If you are using MPICH, it will be compiled in by default, but you need to set the flag `-disable-auto-cleanup` to prevent the process manager from cleaning up all processes after a failure.

Also, because ULFM is not yet part of the standard, functions and constants are prefixed with `MPIX` instead of `MPI`.